# query that will pull data where a certain document type is not found

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am writing a query for a health organization.  The query is to pull patient data, where an encounter/appointment was completed but a chart note was not generated. I have the query pulling patients and their appointments; is there a way to basically say "only show the patients where 'master_im' document was not generated"?

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: What is `master_im`?  What does your table structure and query look like?  This question is hard to answer without more information.

Comment: Check out my comment on the answer below.  I just put some more info on there.  To directly answer your question, 'master_im' is a result that I received from the 'patient_document.document_desc' field.  Right now the query is giving me the list of patients and every document_desc that was in each encounter.

Comment: @user1628034 - Please add that information on your question instead of just leaving it on comments on an answer

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your table structures, etc. your could do a check to see if the `master_im` IS NULL.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE appointment = 'completed'
 AND master_im IS NULL
```

I would advise posting some additional details on your tables.

If the data is stored in separate tables, then you will want to [`JOIN`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) the tables together to get the results you want.

EDIT #1 based on your comment you could do something like this:

```
select *
from person p
inner join appointments a
  on p.enc_id = a.encid
left join patient_documents pd
  on p.enc_id = pd.enc_id
where a.status = 'completed'
  and pd.document_desc != 'master_im'
```

Comment: This might help:  the tables used are 'person', 'appointments', 'patient_documents' for the fields that I am asking about.  They are all joined by using a common field 'enc_id'.

Comment: the master_im is a description in the 'patient_document.document_desc' field